# Merging a lot of different data frames in R

Tags: r, dataframe

I have many data frames and I want to merge them to make one large data frame

For example, I have:

```
month  day  time  h
1      1    23    112
1      2    34    143
1      3    54    352
```

and

```
month  day  time  h
2      1    42    133
2      2    31    342
2      3    55    333
```

They all have the same column names and I want to add them together so that the months are in ascending order in a big data frame of about 60 months.
I'm thinking `x<-do.call("cbind",dataframes)` would do it. But when I try to call `head(x)` to check the data it says `Error in head(x) : object 'x' not found`

Is there a better way to merge/combine these data frames?

I want the output data frame to look like

```
month  day  time  h
1      1    23    112
1      2    34    143
1      3    54    352
...
2      1    42    133
2      2    31    342
2      3    55    333
```

Comment: What is the expected output based on the two datasets?.  If you need to just rbind them `do.call(rbind, listofdataframes)` or if it is `merge`, then `Reduce(function(...) merge(..., by = c('month', 'day', 'time'), listofdataframes)`

Comment: Don't you want `rbind`, not `cbind` ?

Comment: @akrun sorry have added expected output

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use `rbind` instead of `cbind`.

```
do.call(rbind, lst)
```

Or if we are using `data.table`, we can do

```
library(data.table)
rbindlist(lst)
```

Or with `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
bind_rows(lst)
```

where 'lst' is the `list` of 'data.frame'